# Какое свойство отвечает за отступ сверху слов, но не самого меню?

Tags: css

Какое свойство отвечает за то, чтобы опустить слова вниз, при этом не сдвигая само меню.

```css
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: .3s linear;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.topmenu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.topmenu>li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

.topmenu>li>a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FEFDFD;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="left-logo">

  </div>
  <div class="main-menu">


    <nav>
      <ul class="topmenu">
        <li><a href="">Главная</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">Услуги</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Лечебно-оздоровительный массаж</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Стрижка</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извиняюсь, не увидел.

Comment: Всё равно не очень понятно что ты имеешь в виду. Какие слова ты хочешь опускать и в какой низ)

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, забыл добавить скриншот))

Comment: Можешь или паддинги задать для li или line-height ссылке

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Вот как вы можете решить проблему:

```
.topmenu>li>a {
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Добавив `line-height` и дав ему значение как у `height`. И при этом внутренний отступ `padding` сверху и снизу станет бесполезным и можно заменить его на `0`